# Undefined index: Learning php

Tags: php

i am watching tutorials on PHP, and in the video there is this code:

```
$cntr = 1;
$item = 'dummy';

while(!empty($item))
{
    $item_html_name = 'item'.$cntr;
    $item = $_POST[$item_html_name];

    if (!empty($item))
    {
        print "Item: ".$item."<br>";
        $cntr++;
    }
}
```

When i try the code, i get an error "Notice: Undefined index: item1"

here is a screenshot of the video:

[image]

or it may be because of the different PHP versions?

html are also the same:

```
<form action="code1.php" method="post">
    <p>1  <input type="text" name="item1" size="30"></p>
    <p>2  <input type="text" name="item2" size="30"></p>
    <p>3  <input type="text" name="item3" size="30"></p>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: bad tutorial use ` <input type="text" name="item[]" size="30">` then loop the array

Comment: it still doesnt answer my question, but thanks anyway

Comment: is there a check for a post actually being made before the loop?

Comment: No, there wasn't any in the video, but I tried whit and whiteout  making variable for the post. Nothing changed. I have tried many variations, but nothing worked, it drives me crazy.

Comment: on first load there is no post ($_POST) so you will get an error